# Update HTML, with PERL variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script in PERL that print a var (tag) that changes value every second. Actually, I refresh the entire page every 2 seconds, but how update only the perl-tags? The HTML run over a webServer provided by perl, in localhost. Example of code:

```
<h3>{characterName}</h3><br/>
<h4>{characterLocationMap}</h4>
<p>{characterLocationX},{characterLocationY}</p>
```

Comment: Instead of refreshing the entire page, you should make an ajax request every two seconds to your pearl script and return only the html you need to update. When the ajax is finished, upadate the HTML with the ajax response. Does this make sense? Do you need help with an ajax request ?

Comment: The variables "{characterName}" already change every second. The ajax can show this update every second?

Comment: When you say the variable "{characterName}" changes every second you mean it changes on the server but it it not updated in the HTML. I know nothing about PERL so maybe I don't have the right solution. But I do know PHP and do to this I would create a timer that called the PHP script which would return the new value of the variable. When I would get this value, I would simple update the HTML using $('h3').html(variable_value);

Comment: How make this in javascript? Because the webServer(perl) dont run php...